# What's the logic of Gradle dependency resolving

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

In Gradle 6.7, we have a `dependencyManagement.dependencies` to set the defaults for the project.

Recently, someone replaced the individual `dependency` lines for Spring with a `dependencySet`.

```
dependencySet(group: 'org.springframework.boot', version: "2.2.11.RELEASE") {
            entry 'spring-boot-devtools'
            entry 'spring-boot-dependencies'
            entry 'spring-boot-devtools'
            entry 'spring-boot-starter-aop'
            entry 'spring-boot-starter-cache'
            entry 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'
            ...
```

Now after spotting some CVE alerts, I found out that Gradle resolves `spring-boot-starter-cache` to `2.2.8` anyway. I am not sure where it's getting that version from: We don't have it in our project, and the deps tree appears as if we asked for it ourselves (it's at level 0).

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache -> 2.2.8.RELEASE
```

When I add the item explicitly, as we had before for all,

```
dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.2.11.RELEASE'
```

then it ends up being resolved as 2.2.11.

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache -> 2.2.11.RELEASE
```

In Maven, dependency management is very straighforward, compared to this: You control it using dependency management, and BOMs, and all works, no surprises like this.

So maybe I am missing something in Gradle's logic, even after reading the dependency management guide.

How can I use BOM-like `dependencySet` to control all `entry`-es at once? Or do I have wrong assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

> In Gradle 6.7, we have a `dependencyManagement.dependencies` to set the defaults for the project.

Do not confuse Spring's [dependency management Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/) with Gradle's native [dependency mangaement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) functionality. Although they achieve the same goal, they do it in very different ways.

> I am not sure where it's getting that version from: We don't have it in our project, and the deps tree appears as if we asked for it ourselves (it's at level 0).

You can use the `dependencyInsight` task to get more information on a specific dependency and why a specific version was chosen.

```
./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache
```

See [Viewing and debugging dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)
 for more details.

> How can I use BOM-like `dependencySet` to control all `entry`-es at once? Or do I have wrong assumptions?

The docs for the Spring dependency management plugin are clear what you need to do to achieve that: https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-dsl-dependency-sets

If it is not working as you expect, then you need to debug your dependencies as I have linked above.

Also from your examples, my guess is that you have a typical Spring Boot application with the Spring Boot Gradle plugin applied. If so, then the Spring Boot Gradle plugin detects if the Spring dependency management plugin is applied and [automatically imports the Spring Boot BOM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b3970322aa3819c7a41489ce03c571f30fe6dead/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/DependencyManagementPluginAction.java#L36). So there should not be a need to manage Spring specific dependencies as you are.

Comment: Thanks Francisco! Sounds like quite a lot things to check - we have an internal framework which does some of the things you mentioned, but then it's only a dependency of our project, unlike Maven's parent. So I would expect that to be just another source of transitional dependencies. I would prefer to manage the deps in the build script to keep it uniform with other dependencies. If each framework had it's own plugin to manage dependencies, well that would be quite a mess, no?